# Pycharm: Packages installed successfully, but not really - infinite and useless reinstalling

Tags: python, pycharm, package

I started learning Django in encountered very wierd problem.

1. Pycharm says that I need to install some basic packages >
2. I agree and press Install requirements >
3. They are installing >
4. Pycharm says Packages Installed
5. Starts scanning installed packages
6. Doesn't see them.
7. Go to step 1

It looks like that:
[How it looks in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86vUp.png)

I tried googling it, but the answer is mostly "Just install them manuallt through Python Interpreter - that will work".
But it also doesn't. I install it and in doesn't show even in Interpreter menu:
[How it looks in Interpreter Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVTMY.png)

Comment: Are they suggesting that you install them manually in the Python interpreter, or in the *Linux command terminal* using PIP? The latter sounds like the more likely intention, since, well, that's normally how you install Python packages. Alternately, have you checked to see if there are versions of the packages in your system Package Manager (for Mint this would be Synaptic, IIRC) and installed them that way?

Comment: Minor correction - technically, the default Mint package manager is Debian Package Manager (`dpkg`), with `apt-get` and Synaptic being front-ends for it.

Comment: In any case, my speculation is that PyCharm is trying to install the packages globally, but doesn't have the required root permission, nor is it set up to request it. There may be a configuration option or set of options which might control this behavior, by either setting it to request the root pwd, or by setting to install only locally, but I haven't really used PyCharm extensively and wouldn't know.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling PyCharm. If this doesn't work, try to see if anything is interfering with the downloads. Or try reinstalling Python or Django.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).